# memory leak / performance with SSL embedded java on linux

Tags: java, linux, ssl, memory-leaks

Let's see if I can explain my problem properly:
It's the oracle embedded runtime 1.8_201 version I have running on a 2.6.30 embedded linux with an ARMv5 controller, 64M RAM.

The Program communicates with a server via HttpURLConnections without any issues. Performance is good and memory consumption on linux side is stable.
Now, when switching to SSL communication the memory trouble begins...
I'm using the mostly recommended implementation: having a SSLContext, getting the SSLSocketFactory (only once in a static variable) as configuration. Now, the URL.openConnection() gets me the HttpsURLConnection to which I set the SSLSocketFactory.
When reading the inputStream I read it until -1 and then call the .disconnect() on the connection.
This is done every 10s.
What I now watch on Wireshark is following pattern: the connection is started with the usual TLS handshaking and encryption stuff and that the data is transferred fine all within 0.8s. But then, after about 5s, my side (the client) sends an encrypted_Alert to close the connection which then is executed...and after 4s (the remaining time to 10s) the connection is started as above with the whole overhead of TLS handshaking and so on...Why is that so and how can I avoid this? 
The problem that emerges with this procedure is that I run into a memory leak that causes linux to oom-kill the java process...
When getting a java heap dump I see loads of open Finalizer-objects that obviously are consuming the memory.
I then called system.gc() each time I do connection.disconnect  which causes a Full GC that takes about 1s each call. In that case the memory seems to keep a reasonable level and I have no Finalizers in the heap - but then I have this GC timeout (which is exclusive!) and definitley too long.
So what else did I do...
I reduced the interval between the communications to 4s so the timeout to close the connection never occurs...And this is also working fine - memory is not leaking and I have much less open Finalizers.
It would help me a lot if I could set this strange timeout to 15s so I could use my 10s interval as required. Ihave tried to set Http headers with all variations of "keep-alive" but nothing does affect this "autoclose"...
Any ideas how to get this fixed?

 OK, let's break it down to two questions:
- Why are SSL connection objects kept such a long time without getting finalized?
- Why is that HttpsURLConnection closing after 5s and how can I increase this time?

Comment: Can you possibly restructure your question? It is way too long and hard to read? You can highlight main points, so people can answer.

Comment: why call .disconnect() and not .close() ?

Comment: there is no .close() for HttpURLConnection, just .disconnect()

Comment: You're right, sorry I was mismatching with Socket class. You still can call close() of the InputStream class, this should close the connection.Your question is hard to read, would you change it to give some code, and your wireshark capture (in text format it's nice) ?

Comment: You don't have to call `disconnect()`. As you make the next request just some seconds later you can reuse the TCP connection (if the server supports it). Calling `disconnect()` makes it impossible to reuse the connection.